# VPN to specific organization

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have a question about VPN in ubuntu 15.10.
I want to connect a VPN of Lund university, Sweden.
What I have are:
my user-name and the password
Also I'm able to configure the VPN from the network manager, I already connected to another VPN, but I have the three files ca.crt, certificate.crt and key.key,  They are general files so I can use to connect to that VPN?
Also I don't know what's the gateway, it can be connect.lu.se?

At least I wanna know How can I connect to Lund university using my user-name and password, which I used on windows8. Below you can find an explanation of what I do.

The right part shows the main network manager window to create the VPN and the left 4 small windows show the advanced options. In order to get the free vpn work, I write the gateway, user-name,password and the three certificate files downloaded, then I go to the advanced options. First tab (General) I put the port to 443, mark on use LZO compression and use TCP. Second tab just put Cipher to AES_128-CBC

[image]

Thanks,
Elsaid

Comment: You tagged this with "openvpn". Do you have a valid openvpn conf file as well as the three Cert-related files?

Answer (score 1):

Run this:

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

To install the OpenVPN package. Then, make a new file in your home directory, `client.conf`. Edit that file to contain the following:

```
# Specify that we are a client and that we
# will be pulling certain config file directives
# from the server.
client

# Use the same setting as you are using on
# the server.
# On most systems, the VPN will not function
# unless you partially or fully disable
# the firewall for the TUN/TAP interface.
;dev tap
dev tun

# Windows needs the TAP-Win32 adapter name
# from the Network Connections panel
# if you have more than one.  On XP SP2,
# you may need to disable the firewall
# for the TAP adapter.
;dev-node MyTap

# Are we connecting to a TCP or
# UDP server?  Use the same setting as
# on the server.
;proto tcp
proto udp

# The hostname/IP and port of the server.
# You can have multiple remote entries
# to load balance between the servers.
remote connect.lu.se 1194
;remote my-server-2 1194

# Choose a random host from the remote
# list for load-balancing.  Otherwise
# try hosts in the order specified.
;remote-random

# Keep trying indefinitely to resolve the
# host name of the OpenVPN server.  Very useful
# on machines which are not permanently connected
# to the internet such as laptops.
resolv-retry infinite

# Most clients don't need to bind to
# a specific local port number.
nobind

# Downgrade privileges after initialization (non-Windows only)
;user nobody
;group nogroup

# Try to preserve some state across restarts.
persist-key
persist-tun

# If you are connecting through an
# HTTP proxy to reach the actual OpenVPN
# server, put the proxy server/IP and
# port number here.  See the man page
# if your proxy server requires
# authentication.
;http-proxy-retry # retry on connection failures
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port #]

# Wireless networks often produce a lot
# of duplicate packets.  Set this flag
# to silence duplicate packet warnings.
;mute-replay-warnings

# SSL/TLS parms.
# See the server config file for more
# description.  It's best to use
# a separate .crt/.key file pair
# for each client.  A single ca
# file can be used for all clients.
ca ca.crt
cert certificate.crt
key client.key

# Verify server certificate by checking
# that the certicate has the nsCertType
# field set to "server".  This is an
# important precaution to protect against
# a potential attack discussed here:
#  http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm
#
# To use this feature, you will need to generate
# your server certificates with the nsCertType
# field set to "server".  The build-key-server
# script in the easy-rsa folder will do this.
ns-cert-type server

# If a tls-auth key is used on the server
# then every client must also have the key.
;tls-auth ta.key 1

# Select a cryptographic cipher.
# If the cipher option is used on the server
# then you must also specify it here.
;cipher x

# Enable compression on the VPN link.
# Don't enable this unless it is also
# enabled in the server config file.
comp-lzo

# Set log file verbosity.
verb 3

# Silence repeating messages
;mute 20
```

This is a generic client config file for OpenVPN.  Now, to connect, run the following command from your home directory:

```
sudo openvpn client.conf
```

To connect using your given config file.

**MAKE SURE THAT YOUR CA.CRT, CERTIFICATE.CRT, AND KEY.KEY FILES ARE ALSO IN YOUR HOME DIRECTORY**

Comment: Thanks a lot @Heather! It seems not easy for a newbie like me to configure that file. So I wander if there is an easy method through the network manager(Configure VPN) or I have to try with that. I add some pictures to my question shows some options on that manager. Thanks again!

Comment: Openvpn relies on configuration files such as this. You can slightly simplify the process by installing network-manager-openvpn

Comment: The files which I have are from the configuration of free VPN from vpnbook.com. Is that ok?

Comment: Yes, and they will be more tailored to the specific settings of your server. Just make sure they are in the same directory as your certificates, or edit the configuration to include absolute paths to those files

Comment: If so, it should enter by the same configuration as the one from vpnbook.com?? If I'm right I should try to get the right gateway of Lund university (can you give me some hints?) as I'm sure from the user-name and password. I don't understand many lines from your script as I'm new to ubuntu.

Comment: fIinn the question you

Comment: Okay, the gateway seems to be `connect.lu.se`. In the configuration, where it says "User Certificate", "CA Certificate", and "Private Key", you will select the user.crt, ca.crt, and key.key files, respectively. Then you also fill in your given username and password. All should work from there.

Comment: Sorry, please check the question again! Thanks for your fast response

Comment: It doesn't work by the same procedure. Can you guess something to try?

Comment: Maybe omit your username and password, as you usually don't need both a username AND a cert file. Also, check out [this page](https://connect.lu.se/remote/login). Looks like a login page for you.

Comment: Still doesn't work!